# Keeping data in the data field Jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have a php page with input fields.
I gonna put values in these input fields.
What I need is to keep the values in the inputs fields when I go to other php page, where I need get this values.
How can I do?

Comment: There could be many different ways of doing this: submitting the fields in a form, passing the value as parameters in the URL, using cookies, using local storage... picking one method or another will depend on your design.

Answer (score 0):

jQuery isn't made for holding the values of form fields from page-to-page. That's a job for PHP.

If the data from your form needs to be sent to another PHP page, then I'd imagine that sending the data via `POST` variables and dealing with them within the requested PHP page would be appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Use url variables if there aren't too many. There is a good example here:

```
function getUrlParameter(sParam)
{
    var sPageURL = window.location.search.substring(1);
    var sURLVariables = sPageURL.split('&');
    for (var i = 0; i < sURLVariables.length; i++) 
    {
        var sParameterName = sURLVariables[i].split('=');
        if (sParameterName[0] == sParam) 
        {
            return sParameterName[1];
        }
    }
}
```

example: `getUrlParameter('name')` when the url is http://www.example.com/?name=mikey will return string 'mikey'